# Как выполнить принт read файла в открытом уже файле ? Python

Tags: python

Почему я не могу принтовать то что написал в `directionOpen` сразу после открытия.

Если сразу после строки `directionOpen.write(fileOpen.read())` добавить
`print(directionOpen.read())` то выпадает ошибка:
`io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable.`

```
# Copy the first file in another file and read it

fileName = input("What file do you want to copy ? ")
direction = input("Where you want to copy that ? ")

fileOpen = open(fileName, 'r')
directionOpen = open(direction, 'w')

directionOpen.write(fileOpen.read())

fileOpen.close()
directionOpen.close()

forRead = open(direction, 'r')
print(forRead.read())

forRead.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очевидно вы не можете читать что-то из потока открытого на запись.
Флаг `'w'` **(write)** не подразумевает чтение. Измените его на `'w+'` **(write + read)**.

[Подробнее](http://pythonicway.com/python-fileio)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, щас пробовал с w+ он пишет в файле то что надо но принт не делает и ошибок нет незнаю как

Comment: Нашел причину почему нечего не принтует, потому что он читает код с конца. А так нужно использовать directionOpen.seek(0) чтобы он начал читать код с верху. Спасибо вам большое!